# How can I "group" redux store slices under the same property?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm very new to Redux / Redux toolkit, and I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to organize my store state. Basically I'm trying to group multiple slices of my store together but having issue getting typescript to accept it.

What I'm trying to acheive:

```
const fooSlice = createSlice(...);
const barSlice = createSlice(...);
const eggzSlize = createSlice(...);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    myGroupedSlice: {
      // Group these together under a property
      foo: fooSlice.reducer,
      bar: barSlice.reducer,
    },
    eggz: eggzSlize.reducer
  }
});

// Typed hooks - as per the docs
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;

// So I can then use the selectors as such
const barValue = useAppSelector((state) => state.myGroupedSlice.bar);
const eggzValue = useAppSelector((state) => state.eggz);
```

I have tried using `combineReducers` in multiple ways:

- Using it as the value for `myGroupedSlice` like `myGroupedSlice: combineReducers({ foo: fooSlice, bar: barSlice})`. Typescript gives an error if I also add the `eggz` reducer alongside it, and in both cases the `useAppSelector` loses it's typing to `any`.
- Using it to wrap everything like `reducer: combineReducers({ myGroupedSlice: combineReducers(...), eggz: eggzSlice.reducer})`. In this case, typescript doesn't error immediately, but the `useAppSelector` hook will lose it's type to `any`.

In the cases where Typescript technically allows it, I haven't actually tested to see if they're working even with malfunctioning type check.

#### **Edit**

As requested, I have created a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/damp-meadow-w5wrc6

While experimenting with the issue, I realised the problem is actually only ever present when I add a middleware to it; in this case, creating the store as such:

```
export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    myGroupedSlice: combineReducers({
      foo: fooSlice.reducer,
      bar: barSlice.reducer,
    }),
    eggz: eggzSlice.reducer,
  },
  /* 
  The middleware `getDefaultMiddleware` appears to type `myGroupedslice` as 
  `unknown`, leading to a conflict in the `myGroupedSlice` type
  */
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
});
```

Comment: You should be able to use `combineReducers` without issue. What exact error(s) is/are being produced? Could you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the post with a sandbox. This also sent me down the right direction and I figured out the solution, also updated in the post :)

Comment: Your solution was going to be what I was going to suggest/answer with, but wanted to confirm what code you were actually using. Glad you got it sorted out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to the issue: pulling the "definition" of myGroupedSlice outside of the configureStore will evaluate the types correctly:

```
const myGroupedSliceReducers = combineReducers({
  foo: fooSlice.reducer,
  bar: barSlice.reducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    myGroupedSlice: myGroupedSliceReducers,
    eggz: eggzSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
});
// No typescript errors and works correctly
```